# How work with $_request and send multi id in one page?

Tags: php, validation

I want in one page `admin.php` do anything like delete users & delete category.

My existing implementation :

```
<?php 
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($res)){ 
    if($isadmin==1){
        echo"<tr><td><a href=index.php?nw&id=$row->nid><img width=16 height=16 src=img/del.png></a></tr></td>";
    }
    echo"<tr><td><a href=news.php?id=$row->nid>$row->ntitle</a></td></tr><p></p>";
}
echo "</td></tr>";
?>
```

and another line

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM news where nid='$_REQUEST[nw&id]'",$cn);
?>
```

Also do it for category

```
<?php 
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($res)){ 
    if($isadmin==1){
        echo"<tr><td><a href=index.php?id2=$row->cid><img width=16 height=16 src=img/del.png></a>";
    }
    echo "<tr><td><a href=templates.php?id=$row->cid>$row->cname</a></tr></td><p></p>";
}
?>
```

I used id2 and do delete but is it correct ?

Comment: I think that i does not make a difference either you use id or id2

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: Also once you tell me the link to your website, I can delete since the actual deletion doesn't seem to need authentication, only showing the link to it